# What algorithm does google use to make Chrome browser's address bar to act as a default search bar for many websites?

Tags: google-chrome, google-search, searchbar, address-bar

I am wondering what algorithm does google use to make chrome browser's address bar to act as a default search bar for many websites like SO, Quroa etc. but not for facebook, metastackoverflow etc..

For example if you want to search for a topic in stackoverflow, you can do like this in chorme.

[image]

And the search results will directly take you to the stackoverflow page. i.e.

[image]

The same will happen if you choose to search `quora.com` also in chrome's address bar. But this won't happen if you search like `facebook.com` in the address bar and many other websites that have a search bar.

How is this happening? What algorithm does google use to make this happen?

Hope I am clear with my question? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 19):

This feature is powered by what is known as OpenSearch. It allows you to specify how queries are supposed to be formed when searching a website. You can read the documentation here: http://www.opensearch.org/Home

For example, StackOverflow has the following in their HTML source code:

```
<link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="Stack Overflow" href="/opensearch.xml">
```

If you then open the file /opensearch.xml you can see the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns:moz="http://www.mozilla.org/2006/browser/search/">
  <ShortName>Stack Overflow</ShortName>
  <Description>Search Stack Overflow: Q&amp;A for professional and enthusiast programmers</Description>
  <InputEncoding>UTF-8</InputEncoding>
  <Image width="16" height="16" type="image/x-icon">http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico</Image>
  <Url type="text/html" method="get" template="http://stackoverflow.com/search?q={searchTerms}"></Url>
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

The most important part is the line that specifies the search term string in line 7.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome uses search engines mechanism. It is described here how to use it
http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95653&topic=14676&ctx=topic

Chrome automatically identifies search boxes and adds corresponding rules to search engines list. Maybe it's engine relies on document parsing. Hense a particular site may be added or not because of it's search box markup.
https://superuser.com/questions/276069/google-chrome-automatically-adding-websites-to-my-list-of-search-engines

If you want to know about parsing algorithm, the only way i see is to dig through chrome sources

Also, you can edit search engine list manually.

PS: And it's not only chrome's feature, other browsers have similar things. Opera as an example http://tech.gaeatimes.com/index.php/archive/how-to-easily-use-manage-your-search-engines-in-opera-browser/