# Google Chrome: search in this site

Tags: html, search, browser

Some time ago I made a website with wordpress, with my own theme.

Testing the site, discovered an interesting feature in Google Chrome:
If I start typing the address of the website, it says: `Press TAB to search this site`.
By doing this, what I type in the address bar, go to `www.meysite.com/?q = ...`
As if he knew the action of my search forms.

Test on Chrome: open a new tab, type `stack`, for him to suggest `stackoverflow.com` then press TAB and type any term

But this feature is only available after the user accessed the site and did a search. I think at this moment Chrome "learns" how.

My question is: is there any way to notify Chrome (and other browsers) that my site has a form/action to do internal searches?

Comment: I think you can find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196317/what-algorithm-does-google-use-to-make-chrome-browsers-address-bar-to-act-as-a

Answer (score 0):

This feature is called [OpenSearch](http://www.opensearch.org/%20OpenSearch).

Like MartelDroid said, you can just look at how stackoverflow do to use it. On this link you can see code example https://stackoverflow.com/a/14496104/894546